# Render is darker than viewport

Tags: rendering

Good morning.

I'm new in blender and i'm making the donut tutorial but unfortunately i've encountered a problem: my render is much darker than view in viewport. Moreover i noticed, than changing Gamma and exposure in render properties doesn't affect viewport and render at all. I'm using NVidia GeForce 2060RTX notebook version. This problem doesn't appear in my previous notebook with NVidia GeForce GTX1060 on the same file.

[image]

I tried:

Instaling and setting latest NVidia Strudio Driver in GeForce Experience

Rendering using GPU, CPU and integrated graphic card

Changing Cycles Render Device between CUDA and OptiX

Installing NVidia OptiX SDK

Comment: Can you upload the file?

Comment: I found the answer: i had a polish sign in color management file directory and blender couldn't find them